# Clearing specific inputs after Ajax post

Tags: jquery, ajax

The plan is to clear input fields after part of form is sucessfuly posted using ajax. I cannot clear all form, rest of fields are required.
This does not work:

```
 $.ajax({
    url : "http://mysite.lv/projects/addform",
    type: "POST",
    data : myArray,
    success: function(){ 
        document.getElementById("alias").clearForm();
```

Comment: `$('input:textbox').val('');`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply set empty val using `.val('')` for inputs in form. something like this:

```
 $('#alias input[type=textbox]').val('');
```

Comment: i think alias is a form id not input

Comment: op has used it as id.